# Street Fighter VAE - How do I preconfig trial settings by editing game files?

Tags: street-fighter-v

In *Street Fighter V: Arcade Edition* PC version, I would like to change the preset Trial mode settings so that it would:

- repeat every trial and only moves to another trial when I set it
- show keys pressed on the right

These switches are there but it is tedious to change those every time I enter trial mode.

I have checked tutorials of editing game files, but they are mainly for mods. And the 'assets' files are encrypted (I think), and cannot be opened with Unreal engine editor.

What can I do?